# How to ssh using ActiveState's 'Expect' for Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, expect, activestate

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out, mush less find, a tutorial that shows how to use ActiveState's Expect utility to ssh to another server.  I cannot find how to simply ssh into a server and run something simple (like 'ls') and disconnect.

The demos folder does not contain the tkremotes.tcl script the documentation claims, but I did find a copy of it [here](https://github.com/dineshkummarc/expect-src/blob/master/demos/tkremotels.tcl). Looking at this, I don't understand how they are making the ssh connection, if at all.

Comment: Use ssh keys and just do `ssh user@remote ls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [KiTTY](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Internet/Telnet-SSH-Clients/Portable-KiTTY.shtml) (modded version of PuTTY). It has everything you need: saves password & user, executes commands and exits automatically).

Comment: Didn't really consider this an answer but sadly this is really the ONLY way to accomplish this on a Windows box I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2018, as detailled with "[Windows Command-Line: Introducing the Windows Pseudo Console (ConPTY)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/)", Windows 10 does have an option natively.

The issue was:

> One of those weaknesses is that Windows tries to be “helpful” but gets in the way of alternative and 3rd party Console developers, service developers, etc.
>
> When building a Console or service, developers need to be able to access/supply the communication pipes through which their Terminal/service communicates with command-line applications.
> In the *NIX world, this isn’t a problem because *NIX provides a “Pseudo Terminal” (PTY) infrastructure which makes it easy to build the communication plumbing for a Console or service, but Windows does not … until now!

But, as illustrated with [`creack/pty`](https://github.com/creack/pty) (a Go package for using unix pseudo-terminals) and its [issue 95](https://github.com/creack/pty/issues/95), this new feature is not always integrated.

That issue just referenced now (Nov. 2020) [conpty](https://github.com/ActiveState/termtest/tree/master/conpty) from ActiveTest:

> Support for the Windows pseudo console in Go.
>
> Developed as part of the cross-platform terminal automation library **[`expect`](https://github.com/ActiveState/termtest/expect)** for the [ActiveState state tool](https://www.activestate.com/products/platform/state-tool/).

So Windows support for `expect` might finally be here! (7 years later)